# characterIndexAtPoint in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, text

I'm new to objective-c, and I've done this in Flex/Actionscript, but hitting a wall with IOS.  Is it possible to get the index of a character under a point(x,y) in a TextField or Label and then be able to modify that single character in IOS?

I have a TapGestureRecognizer coming in with a point in my view.  I need to now be able to isolate and highlight just the character at the point coming in.

For example if I have the text "Hello" on screen and I ask them to click on the 'e', I need to know which letter they touch and highlight it green/red depending on if they were right or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITextField` (and `UITextView`) conforms to the `UITextInput` protocol which has the method `characterRangeAtPoint:`.

Once you have the `CGPoint` from the gesture, use this method on the text field to get a `UITextRange`. Then use the `textInRange:` method to get the text associated with that range.